# kube-api server is not starting (CrashLoopBackOff)

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, kube-apiserver, coreos-ignition

i am unable to start the kube-apiserver on my 1 master node cluster. the kubelet keeps on trying to start the service but get all the time CrashLoopBackOff. 
i tried to run the container using the `docker run` command and i m getting the following log
i don't understand why i can't see the service `6443` or `443` on listening when i do `netstat`.

```
core@core-01 ~ $ etcdctl get /coreos.com/network/subnets/10.2.41.0-24
{"PublicIP":"10.0.2.11","BackendType":"vxlan","BackendData":{"VtepMAC":"e2:41:48:bc:6e:31"}}

core@core-01 ~ $ etcdctl get /coreos.com/network/config
{ "Network": "10.2.0.0/16", "SubnetLen": 24, "Backend": { "Type": "vxlan", "VNI": 1 } }

core@core-01 ~ $ etcdctl cluster-health
member b12eaa0af14319e0 is healthy: got healthy result from https://10.0.2.11:2379
cluster is healthy


core@core-01 ~ $ journalctl -fu flanneld
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-01-05 20:09:44 UTC. --
Jan 05 20:30:11 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:11.451701     829 iptables.go:137] Deleting iptables rule: ! -s 10.2.0.0/16 -d 10.2.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
Jan 05 20:30:11 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:11.455149     829 iptables.go:125] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.2.0.0/16 -d 10.2.0.0/16 -j RETURN
Jan 05 20:30:11 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:11.464136     829 iptables.go:125] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.2.0.0/16 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j MASQUERADE
Jan 05 20:30:11 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:11.483193     829 iptables.go:125] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.2.0.0/16 -d 10.2.67.0/24 -j RETURN
Jan 05 20:30:11 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:11.503353     829 iptables.go:125] Adding iptables rule: ! -s 10.2.0.0/16 -d 10.2.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
Jan 05 20:30:12 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:12.178567     829 iptables.go:115] Some iptables rules are missing; deleting and recreating rules
Jan 05 20:30:12 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:12.178601     829 iptables.go:137] Deleting iptables rule: -s 10.2.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
Jan 05 20:30:12 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:12.182925     829 iptables.go:137] Deleting iptables rule: -d 10.2.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
Jan 05 20:30:12 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:12.184853     829 iptables.go:125] Adding iptables rule: -s 10.2.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
Jan 05 20:30:12 core-01 flannel-wrapper[829]: I0105 20:30:12.191388     829 iptables.go:125] Adding iptables rule: -d 10.2.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT


core@core-01 ~ $ journalctl -fu etcd-member
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-01-05 20:09:44 UTC. --
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.402265 I | raft: b12eaa0af14319e0 became leader at term 3
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.402436 I | raft: raft.node: b12eaa0af14319e0 elected leader b12eaa0af14319e0 at term 3
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.407687 I | etcdserver: published {Name:core-01 ClientURLs:[https://10.0.2.11:2379]} to cluster f42ef6de7357f6b9
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.409961 I | embed: ready to serve client requests
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.413929 I | embed: serving client requests on 127.0.0.1:2379
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.414398 I | embed: ready to serve client requests
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.414844 I | embed: serving client requests on 10.0.2.11:2379
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.415087 I | embed: ready to serve client requests
Jan 05 20:30:01 core-01 etcd-wrapper[724]: 2020-01-05 20:30:01.416808 I | embed: serving client requests on 127.0.0.1:4001

core@core-01 ~ $ docker run -v /etc/kubernetes/ssl/:/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0 /hyperkube apiserver --etcd-servers="https://10.0.2.11:2379" --allow-privileged=true  --service-cluster-ip-range="10.3.0.0/24" --secure-port=443 --advertise-address=10.0.2.11 --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true --anonymous-auth=true
W0105 20:25:36.153523       1 authentication.go:362] AnonymousAuth is not allowed with the AllowAll authorizer.  Resetting AnonymousAuth to false. You should use a different authorizer
E0105 20:25:37.548076       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:70: Failed to list *api.Secret: Get https://localhost:443/api/v1/secrets?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
[restful] 2020/01/05 20:25:37 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://10.0.2.11:443/swaggerapi/
[restful] 2020/01/05 20:25:37 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] https://10.0.2.11:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
I0105 20:25:38.096619       1 serve.go:79] Serving securely on 0.0.0.0:443
I0105 20:25:38.097522       1 serve.go:94] Serving insecurely on 127.0.0.1:8080
I0105 20:26:07.098874       1 trace.go:61] Trace "Create /api/v1/namespaces" (started 2020-01-05 20:25:38.179779805 +0000 UTC):
[40.586µs] [40.586µs] About to convert to expected version
[1.500802ms] [1.460216ms] Conversion done
[1.506436ms] [5.634µs] About to store object in database
"Create /api/v1/namespaces" [28.918989614s] [28.917483178s] END
E0105 20:26:07.100872       1 client_ca_hook.go:58] Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration
W0105 20:26:36.010336       1 storage_extensions.go:127] third party resource sync failed: the server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again later (get thirdpartyresources.extensions)
E0105 20:26:36.381565       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:70: Failed to list *api.Secret: the server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again later (get secrets)
E0105 20:26:36.936321       1 storage_rbac.go:140] unable to initialize clusterroles: the server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again later (get clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io)
E0105 20:27:34.774087       1 storage_rbac.go:140] unable to initialize clusterroles: the server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again later (get clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io)
F0105 20:27:34.774160       1 hooks.go:110] PostStartHook "rbac/bootstrap-roles" failed: unable to initialize roles: timed out waiting for the condition

core@core-01 ~ $ journalctl -fu kubelet
-- Logs begin at Sun 2020-01-05 20:09:44 UTC. --
Jan 05 20:43:53 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:43:53.245043     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:768] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)Jan 05 20:43:53 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: E0105 20:43:53.245448     745 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15 ("kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"
Jan 05 20:43:53 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:43:53.426322     745 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jan 05 20:44:03 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:03.484748     745 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jan 05 20:44:04 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:04.932047     745 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jan 05 20:44:05 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:05.246439     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:514] Container {Name:kube-apiserver Image:quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0 Command:[/hyperkube apiserver --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --etcd-servers="https://10.0.2.11:2379" --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range="10.3.0.0/24" --secure-port=443 --advertise-address=10.0.2.11 --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota --tls-cert-file=/etc/ssl/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/ssl/certs/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/etc/ssl/certs/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true --anonymous-auth=false] Args:[] WorkingDir: Ports:[{Name:https HostPort:443 ContainerPort:443 Protocol:TCP HostIP:} {Name:local HostPort:8080 ContainerPort:8080 Protocol:TCP HostIP:}] EnvFrom:[] Env:[] Resources:{Limits:map[] Requests:map[]} VolumeMounts:[{Name:ssl-certs-kubernetes ReadOnly:true MountPath:/etc/kubernetes/ssl SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>} {Name:ssl-certs-host ReadOnly:true MountPath:/etc/ssl/certs SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>}] VolumeDevices:[] LivenessProbe:&Probe{Handler:Handler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:&HTTPGetAction{Path:/healthz,Port:8080,Host:127.0.0.1,Scheme:HTTP,HTTPHeaders:[],},TCPSocket:nil,},InitialDelaySeconds:15,TimeoutSeconds:15,PeriodSeconds:10,SuccessThreshold:1,FailureThreshold:3,} ReadinessProbe:nil Lifecycle:nil TerminationMessagePath:/dev/termination-log TerminationMessagePolicy:File ImagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent SecurityContext:nil Stdin:false StdinOnce:false TTY:false} is dead, but RestartPolicy says that we should restart it.Jan 05 20:44:05 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:05.247913     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:758] checking backoff for container "kube-apiserver" in pod "kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"Jan 05 20:44:05 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:05.248683     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:768] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)
Jan 05 20:44:05 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: E0105 20:44:05.249152     745 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15 ("kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"
Jan 05 20:44:13 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:13.542958     745 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jan 05 20:44:17 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:17.960004     745 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Jan 05 20:44:18 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:18.309348     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:514] Container {Name:kube-apiserver Image:quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.1_coreos.0 Command:[/hyperkube apiserver --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --etcd-servers="https://10.0.2.11:2379" --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range="10.3.0.0/24" --secure-port=443 --advertise-address=10.0.2.11 --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota --tls-cert-file=/etc/ssl/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/ssl/certs/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/etc/ssl/certs/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true --anonymous-auth=false] Args:[] WorkingDir: Ports:[{Name:https HostPort:443 ContainerPort:443 Protocol:TCP HostIP:} {Name:local HostPort:8080 ContainerPort:8080 Protocol:TCP HostIP:}] EnvFrom:[] Env:[] Resources:{Limits:map[] Requests:map[]} VolumeMounts:[{Name:ssl-certs-kubernetes ReadOnly:true MountPath:/etc/kubernetes/ssl SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>} {Name:ssl-certs-host ReadOnly:true MountPath:/etc/ssl/certs SubPath: MountPropagation:<nil>}] VolumeDevices:[] LivenessProbe:&Probe{Handler:Handler{Exec:nil,HTTPGet:&HTTPGetAction{Path:/healthz,Port:8080,Host:127.0.0.1,Scheme:HTTP,HTTPHeaders:[],},TCPSocket:nil,},InitialDelaySeconds:15,TimeoutSeconds:15,PeriodSeconds:10,SuccessThreshold:1,FailureThreshold:3,} ReadinessProbe:nil Lifecycle:nil TerminationMessagePath:/dev/termination-log TerminationMessagePolicy:File ImagePullPolicy:IfNotPresent SecurityContext:nil Stdin:false StdinOnce:false TTY:false} is dead, but RestartPolicy says that we should restart it.
Jan 05 20:44:18 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:18.311411     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:758] checking backoff for container "kube-apiserver" in pod "kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"
Jan 05 20:44:18 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: I0105 20:44:18.312089     745 kuberuntime_manager.go:768] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)
Jan 05 20:44:18 core-01 kubelet-wrapper[745]: E0105 20:44:18.313299     745 pod_workers.go:186] Error syncing pod c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15 ("kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "kube-apiserver" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=kube-apiserver pod=kube-apiserver-10.0.2.11_kube-system(c1d216376c7569eb905e9536d6c7bf15)"
```

**EDIT** updating the version doesn't solve the issue

```
core@core-01 ~ $ docker run -v /etc/kubernetes/ssl/:/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.9.6_coreos.2 /hyperkube apiserver --etcd-servers="https://10.0.2.11:2379" --allow-privileged=true  --service-cluster-ip-range="10.3.0.0/24" --secure-port=443 --advertise-address=10.0.2.11 --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client.pem --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-etcd-client-key.pem --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true --anonymous-auth=true      
I0106 23:10:42.463150       1 server.go:121] Version: v1.9.6+coreos.2
W0106 23:10:42.463629       1 authentication.go:378] AnonymousAuth is not allowed with the AllowAll authorizer.  Resetting AnonymousAuth to false. You should use a different authorizer
I0106 23:10:42.699897       1 master.go:225] Using reconciler: master-count
W0106 23:10:42.751993       1 genericapiserver.go:342] Skipping API batch/v2alpha1 because it has no resources.
W0106 23:10:42.795606       1 genericapiserver.go:342] Skipping API rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1 because it has no resources.
W0106 23:10:42.796803       1 genericapiserver.go:342] Skipping API storage.k8s.io/v1alpha1 because it has no resources.
W0106 23:10:42.858587       1 genericapiserver.go:342] Skipping API admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1 because it has no resources.
[restful] 2020/01/06 23:10:43 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://10.0.2.11:443/swaggerapi
[restful] 2020/01/06 23:10:43 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https://10.0.2.11:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
[restful] 2020/01/06 23:10:43 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://10.0.2.11:443/swaggerapi
[restful] 2020/01/06 23:10:43 log.go:33: [restful/swagger] https://10.0.2.11:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
I0106 23:10:49.341498       1 insecure_handler.go:121] Serving insecurely on 0.0.0.0:8080
I0106 23:10:49.343053       1 serve.go:89] Serving securely on [::]:443
I0106 23:10:49.343268       1 apiservice_controller.go:112] Starting APIServiceRegistrationController
I0106 23:10:49.343391       1 cache.go:32] Waiting for caches to sync for APIServiceRegistrationController controller
I0106 23:10:49.346030       1 crd_finalizer.go:242] Starting CRDFinalizer
I0106 23:10:49.346531       1 available_controller.go:262] Starting AvailableConditionController
I0106 23:10:49.346710       1 cache.go:32] Waiting for caches to sync for AvailableConditionController controller
I0106 23:10:49.346838       1 controller.go:84] Starting OpenAPI AggregationController
I0106 23:10:49.348542       1 crdregistration_controller.go:110] Starting crd-autoregister controller
I0106 23:10:49.348697       1 controller_utils.go:1019] Waiting for caches to sync for crd-autoregister controller
I0106 23:10:49.349227       1 customresource_discovery_controller.go:152] Starting DiscoveryController
I0106 23:10:49.349338       1 naming_controller.go:274] Starting NamingConditionController
E0106 23:11:49.368395       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/pkg/client/informers/internalversion/factory.go:73: Failed to list *apiextensions.CustomResourceDefinition: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io)
E0106 23:11:49.370175       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get services)
E0106 23:11:49.370252       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:85: Failed to list *core.Secret: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get secrets)
E0106 23:11:49.370287       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get endpoints)
E0106 23:11:49.371136       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kube-aggregator/pkg/client/informers/internalversion/factory.go:73: Failed to list *apiregistration.APIService: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io)
I0106 23:12:20.349799       1 trace.go:76] Trace[1298498081]: "Create /api/v1/namespaces" (started: 2020-01-06 23:11:50.348500756 +0000 UTC m=+68.076132988) (total time: 30.001224437s):
Trace[1298498081]: [30.001224437s] [30.000912177s] END
E0106 23:12:20.350998       1 client_ca_hook.go:78] Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration
E0106 23:12:50.369445       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/pkg/client/informers/internalversion/factory.go:73: Failed to list *apiextensions.CustomResourceDefinition: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io)
E0106 23:12:50.371400       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Service: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get services)
E0106 23:12:50.372842       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:85: Failed to list *core.Secret: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get secrets)
E0106 23:12:50.373942       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get endpoints)
E0106 23:12:50.375319       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kube-aggregator/pkg/client/informers/internalversion/factory.go:73: Failed to list *apiregistration.APIService: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io)
I0106 23:13:50.353033       1 trace.go:76] Trace[2019727887]: "Create /api/v1/namespaces" (started: 2020-01-06 23:13:20.352630686 +0000 UTC m=+158.080262917) (total time: 30.000382718s):
Trace[2019727887]: [30.000382718s] [30.000344689s] END
E0106 23:13:50.353369       1 client_ca_hook.go:78] Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration
F0106 23:13:50.353386       1 hooks.go:188] PostStartHook "ca-registration" failed: unable to initialize client CA configmap: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Comment: First thing I'd advise is using a much more up-to-date version of Kubernetes. 1.6 is is 3 years old.

Comment: Hello
i tried the newest version and i still get the same error

Comment: are you using kubeadm to create your k8s cluster? If so it may happen that you did not clear up the previous installation properly and because of that some process is already runnning on 6443 port.

Comment: Can you try `--anonymous-auth=false`, rather than true?

Comment: @favoretti, Already done that ... doesn't change anything

Comment: @RohanMehto, No i am using ignition files, so every time i boot the coreos instance, it's a fresh installation

Comment: try checking again if some process is alreay listening on port 6443 for tcp6 too. And also use the netstat command as root user. Check if that shows something.

Comment: @RohanMehto i already checked that, nothing is running on 6443, 443 nor 8080. (i don't currently have access to my lab, i will post the netstat result as soon as i can)

Comment: Did you update everything to the newest version? Did you deploy it using following link: https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/blob/master/Documentation/deploy-master.md

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the node.

```
#!/bin/sh
docker rm -f $(docker ps -qa)
docker volume prune -f
cleanupdirs="/var/lib/etcd /etc/kubernetes /etc/cni /opt/cni /var/lib/cni /var/run/calico /opt/rke"
for dir in $cleanupdirs; do
  echo "Removing $dir"
  rm -rf $dir
done
```

---

**Source**: https://gist.github.com/superseb/2cf186726807a012af59a027cb41270d